# iOS Beginner: TextField doesn't show result of my calculation

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to programming in general and currently trying to get a foot 
into Objective-C. Like to write my first app for the iPhone, should 
be a simple Golf app (for now). You enter your holes played and 
strokes needed on the green and the app tells you what your average is.

When it comes to displaying the result in an UITextField I get lost.

I thought the ollowing code would work but the result is not showing:

```
- (IBAction)calcNow(id)sender 
{

int holes = [[holesField text] intValue]; 

int strokes = [[strokesField text] intValue]; 

double result = strokes / holes; 

[averageField setText:result]; 
}
```

Note:

The book I am reading tells me that a number, entered in an UITextField
must be converted before I'm able to work with the value as a number.

I think this will do it:

```
[[holesField text] intValue];
```

Is this correct?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi! Could you edit your post and wrap your code in those grey boxes, which you see here everywhere? This makes it easier to read.

Comment: Of course, will do next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is use:

```
[averageField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",result]];
```

Because setText: uses a `NSString` class as message.

Comment: That was easy. Thank you for your code AND the explanation. This is exactly what helps us beginners getting started.

Comment: Glad to be able to help! To close this question you can mark it as the correct answer :D